# what would the drain voltage be if NMOS source voltage is not ground?

Tags: transistors, nmos, source

[image]

Hi I'm a beginner trying to learn CMOS cuicuit.

Let's say we have two NMOS connected as shown.
Given: A, B, C are connected to Vdd = 5V; 
VtM1 = 0.6V is the threshold voltage of M1; 
VtM2 = 0.5V  is the threshold voltage of M2.

Could someone please explain why the voltage of node "y" is Vy = Vdd - VtM1 - VtM2 ?
(which means if the input of M2, Vx = 5V - 0.6V = 4.4V, the output of M2 is Vy = 4.4V - 0.5V = 3.9V ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage at node Y ***is not*** what you say it is:

$$V_Y\ne V_{DD}-V_{THM1}-V_{THM2}$$

Rather,

$$V_Y=V_{DD}-max\left(V_{THM1},V_{THM2}\right)$$

So, for \$V_{DD}=5\rm{V}\$, \$V_{THM1}=0.6\rm{V}\$, and \$V_{THM2}=0.5\rm{V}\$, then \$V_Y=4.4\rm{V}\$. M1 is in saturation with \$V_{DSM1}=0.6\rm{V}\$, while M2 is in triode with \$V_{DSM2}=0\rm{V}\$.

If you flipped them around, so that \$V_{THM1}=0.5\rm{V}\$ and \$V_{THM2}=0.6\rm{V}\$, then they would both be in saturation. M1 would have \$V_{DSM1}=0.5\rm{V}\$, and M2 would have \$V_{DSM2}=0.1\rm{V}\$. \$V_Y\$ would still be \$4.4\rm{V}\$.

I should note that, since the body is disconnected from the S/D terminals, these MOSFETs will experience body effect. Therefore their threshold voltages will be substantially higher than we have considered in this analysis.

Comment: Hi Zeke, I've elaborated my original question a little bit. Do you know the answer?